# How to identify public holiday

Tags: python

Is there any code in python that enables the calendar to identify public holidays, so that i can disable buttons when it is a public holiday.

Tried searching on google, but couldn't find relevant problems..

Comment: I guess you will have to import a list of public holidays for your region. There is no universal public holiday algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [python-holidays](https://github.com/dr-prodigy/python-holidays) package that has the holidays of lot of countries. You can use it to check if a date is a holiday.

```
from datetime import date

import holidays

us_holidays = holidays.UnitedStates()
# or:
# us_holidays = holidays.US()
# or:
# us_holidays = holidays.CountryHoliday('US')
# or, for specific prov / states:
# us_holidays = holidays.CountryHoliday('US', prov=None, state='CA')

date(2015, 1, 1) in us_holidays  # True
date(2015, 1, 2) in us_holidays  # False
```

It also allows you to create your own custom holiday objects.